# Advice on torching my lawn

Tags: lawn

I don't like mowing my lawn (too sisyphean). I'd like to go about a year in between having to do anything. So I'm thinking about torching it with a weed burner.

How's that likely to work out for me?

[image: weed burner]

Comment: Slower and much more tedious than mowing, I'd say.   Just don't mow it. The city will come by and mow it. There'll be some blah blah blah about money,  but at the end of things it'll just get paid for automatically when you sell the house.

Comment: Get rid of your lawn?

Comment: Go ahead and torch (kill) your lawn if you want. It will grow back soon enough (presuming it gets watered, naturally or by you) but instead of nice grass it will be all types of weeds, then you can fire up the flamethrower and torch *those*.

Comment: That was a standard technique to kill weeds in crop fields before fuel got so expensive.

Comment: How big a lawn we talking... quarter acre, four acres?

Comment: you should change your username to `MowZero`

Comment: When the weeds come back they'll grow four times as fast!